# Algolia Secured API Keys: attributesToRetrieve parameter

Tags: algolia

with Algolia is it possible to restrict the attributes to retrieve when building a Secured API Key?

By defualt, when searching, [attributesToRetrieve](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters#attributestoretrieve) parameter may be used, however I am not sure if it's possible to get used [during the generation of a Secured API key](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys#how-it-works).

The reason of this is because we want to restrict certain attributes of a document to specific users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to restrict the attributes to retrieve using the `attributesToRetrieve` query parameter while generating the Secured API key ->  the user will still be able to override it at query time.

The only thing you can do is configure the `unretrievableAttributes` setting in your index settings. This setting forces some attributes to be non-retrievable whatever the `attributeTo{Retrieve,Highlight,Snippet}` query parameter you set.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I allow then specific users to retrieve them? Let's say they are business-internal attributes we wish to show only to our employees.

Comment: I think there are 2 options: either you use the ADMIN API key internally (this key is able to bypass the `unretrievableAttributes` restriction); or you use multiple indices (1 with restrictions, 1 without) and you use one or the other depending on the ACL of your users.